# NVIDIA RTX Titan (24GB, Professional) With Razer Core X Chroma

Tags: graphics-card, macbook-pro

I have discussed the last two days with the Razer support, and we have come to no solution. I was wondering if the NVIDIA RTX Titan (24GB, Professional) will also work with the Razer Core X Chroma? The RTX Titan is not on the supported cards list, and therefore, Razer does not want to say anything.

They don't even say it "could or it could not work." I was hoping to find here some help, and maybe some ideas and suggestions if I should try and buy it? Or should I go for the NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti? I need some high-end card with USB C output.

Why should the RTX Titan NOT work?

Supported Cards: https://support.razer.com/gaming-laptops/razer-core-x/

Thank you in advance for the advice!

Regards

Comment: 2080ti is a much better option.

Comment: @NiallJones Thank you! While searching online for the NVIDIA GEFORCE RTX 2080Ti I can only find modified versions of MSI Asus and others... The razer support says that they guaranty the compatibility with the original one. But after researching for 1 hour I only saw the original version on Nvidia.com ... The thing is I am based in Switzerland and they don't send to here... Do you think it does matter if I buy the MSI GeForce RTX 2080 Ti Lightning Z (11GB, High End)? Could there appear any issues?

Comment: Any 2089 TI will work.  All 2080 TIs use the same chip.

Comment: I don’t see why it wouldn’t work as long as it physically fits and doesn’t draw too much power, which you should check.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: NVidia don't make graphics cards, they only make graphics chipsets. Anything you see marked as 'Founder's Edition' or otherwise marked as 'by NVidia' is actually made by PNY... so unless Razer will only support the PNY, they're talking nonsense.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you! You are so right, I have just bought the ASUS GeForce RTX 2080 Ti ROG STRIX O11G! Thank you, everyone, once again!